# show only one date picker when creating new appointment telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

Can i create a new appointment inside rad Scheduler based on a single date(select only one day without the need of selecting start date and end date)
For example if we have an occasion like birthday the user should have only one date picker to select the day of the birthday without the need of selecting start day and end day.
 
Please review the attached picture to help you understand more what i need.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6OP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik supports creating custom Scheduler Edit form Templates.  See any of the links below for sample code:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scheduler/how-to/customize-the-advanced-form-template

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/raddock/defaultcs.aspx

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/advancedformtemplate/defaultcs.aspx

It should also be possible to intercept the client-side event when the edit form is being shown and hide the control you want hidden at that time.

http://blogs.msmvps.com/bmains/2010/08/15/telerik-radscheduler-client-side-capabilities-part-2-the-advanced-form/